# Understanding android object to string result

Tags: android

```
MyObject object;
Log.i("print",object.toString());
```

it will either print `MyObject{a7126a58 #0 id=0x7f100007}` or `MyObject{a7126a58}`. My program will would only if it prints `MyObject{a7126a58}`. I think it's the address of the object. But I don't know what does `#0 id=0x7f100007` mean?

Comment: Usually # = numer of...

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is the [hashCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29) of your object.

Comment: I think this must be comment

Comment: @Nilesh It might be short but it IS an answer to the OPs question